# Difference between ways to run a function asynchronously

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

What is the difference between?

```
asyncio.run(func())
```

and

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(func())
```

As far as I understand, the difference is that if I use the first example in a program that already has `event_loop`, then a conflict will occur.

Comment: What exactly are you interested in? The [``asyncio.run`` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run) links to the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/asyncio/runners.py), which obviously many things differently. Are you interested in the actual differences, or just whether you should use ``asyncio.run`` in place of the older pattern?

Comment: In a nutshell, the difference is that `asyncio.run` sets up a fresh event loop, whereas `run_until_complete` can be called multiple times with different awaitables under the same loop, possibly reusing background tasks and other loop-specific state. `asyncio.run` is almost certainly what you want; `run_until_complete` is now considered a low-level API for specialized purposes.

Comment: @user4815162342 I found this code [here](https://github.com/SharpBit/brawlstats/blob/master/examples/async.py). I decided to understand the difference

Comment: You probably intended to address that to @MisterMiyagi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [the source for `asyncio.run`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L8) will give you your answer:

```py
def run(main, *, debug=False):
    """Execute the coroutine and return the result.
    This function runs the passed coroutine, taking care of
    managing the asyncio event loop and finalizing asynchronous
    generators.
    This function cannot be called when another asyncio event loop is
    running in the same thread.
    If debug is True, the event loop will be run in debug mode.
    This function always creates a new event loop and closes it at the end.
    It should be used as a main entry point for asyncio programs, and should
    ideally only be called once.
    Example:
        async def main():
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            print('hello')
        asyncio.run(main())
    """
    if events._get_running_loop() is not None:
        raise RuntimeError(
            "asyncio.run() cannot be called from a running event loop")

    if not coroutines.iscoroutine(main):
        raise ValueError("a coroutine was expected, got {!r}".format(main))

    loop = events.new_event_loop()
    try:
        events.set_event_loop(loop)
        loop.set_debug(debug)
        return loop.run_until_complete(main)
    finally:
        try:
            _cancel_all_tasks(loop)
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
            loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_default_executor())
        finally:
            events.set_event_loop(None)
            loop.close()
```

As you can see, it throws an Exception if a loop is already running in the current thread, then creates its own loop and calls `run_until_complete` on it. The other additional parts compared to your second code snippet is that it validates if the function you passed to it is a coroutine, and that it handles shutting everything down cleanly after the coroutine you passed to it has completed.

As its docstring says, it's intended to be used as a entry point into `asyncio` applications.